# jQuery firing click event without a click

Tags: jquery, events, chaining

Well, that's kind of what happens.

```
$('.js-custom-dropdown').find('.custom-dropdown-unfolded').toggle();
$('.custom-dropdown-btn, .custom-dropdown-btn-unfolded').keydown(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        openDropdown($(this));
    }
}).click( function(){
    openDropdown($(this));
});

function openDropdown (element){
    element.parents('.js-custom-dropdown').find('.custom-dropdown-unfolded').toggle();
    console.log($(this))
}
```

When I click the dropdown button, `openDropdown` function is executed once, but when I Tab my way to the button and press enter, the function is called twice. Guess that has something to do with chaining, but I admit that I'm new to this and don't fully understand jQuery design patterns. I could of cource call the function twice in `keydown` handler and that would solve the problem, but.. you know :)

Could you please explain what's wrong with the code and what causes such behavior?

Comment: is it not because you have 2 event listeners - one for keydown (which will fire when you press enter) and the other for when the button is clicked (which I guess is what you are doing when you press enter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is down to html 5 user interactions specifications. If you take a look at the [HTML spec for elements with a tabIndex](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) you'll find they mention that for any element with a tab index the enter key causes a click event.

I suspect that is what's causing this behaviour. You could try it on an older (non-html 5 compliant) browser to test whether this is the case.

Edit (as requested by poster): The [answer given by @Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15655361/20992) provides a way to remedy the issue you're having. Using jquery's "preventDefault" on the event will stop it being hit twice when you hit enter.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the right answer. I've tested the page in IE7, and I was able to open the dropdown with the Enter key. I didn't have acess to JS console though. Although, could you please suggest a way that I could make this to work in all browsers?

Comment: I'll accept your answer because it answers the question that I've posted, yet could you please cite the other one with the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the click event on keydown using: `$(this).trigger('click');`, and the preventing the default action upon keydown:

```
$('.custom-dropdown-btn, .custom-dropdown-btn-unfolded').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(this).trigger('click');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}).click(function () {
    openDropdown($(this));
});
```

Here's a proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yTuR3/

Comment: e.preventDefault() is sufficient. Thank you for your help